# Switch maximum and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we have a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ that is continuous, decreasing, assumes a maximum at the origin, and Lebesgue integrable. Using the layer-cake formula one may write $f(x) = \int_0^{\infty} 1_{ \{f \geq s\}}$.   What conditions must be put on a density $\phi$ for the following to happen? Is translations invariance a necessaity?

$$
\max_{w \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\{\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{\{f \geq s\} + w} \phi(x) dx ds\right\} = \int_0^{\infty} \max_{w \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \left\{ \int_{\{f \geq s\} + w} \phi(x) dx  \right\} ds?
$$

Comment: Sure, the inner integral is independent of $w$.

Comment: That's a fair point, Lebesgue measure is translation invariant. I wanted something more complicated, say a decaying density $\phi$. I'll amend that now.

Comment: Aren't both sides always maximized by $w=0$?